# formatted my dell and lost the sata drivers

Tags: windows-7, format, sata

i formatted my dell studio 1555 laptop hard drive and when i try to install windows 7 it shows up a message that says

> " a required cd/dvd drive devise driver is missing . if you have a driver floppy disk, cd, dvd, or usb flash drive, please insert now."

i searched the internet about this message they say that it might be the installation cd is damaged but i tried more than one ,,
others say that i need to set the sata drivers via a usb i also tried this but it didn'y=t work !!

anyone has any idea about such problem and how it can be fixed ?!!!

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Does your DELL have a Service-Tag? 
Normally you can find those Drivers at DELL itself here: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriversHome/NeedProductSelection

Comment: thanks jenson it did not work my laptop is formatted so i can't install any driver !!

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your system and press F2 to BIOS menu, check sata staus, if CD device detected?
what did you use, ex-CD or the CD device inside?

about installtion, press F12 into boot menu, select CD/DVD item. if you use ext-USB CD device, choose USB item.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the total solution, get here:-

https://rahulstech2000.blogspot.com/2019/07/a-required-cddvd-drive-device-driver-is.html?m=1

Comment: you should explain the solution in here, don't just post a link.